# Why when navigating to a site using webbBrowser i'm getting null exception all the time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In constructor:

```
webBrowser2.Navigate("http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums/forumpage/393");
```

Then in DocumentCompleted:

```
void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlElementCollection items = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
            foreach (HtmlElement item in items)
            {
                if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "addMessage")
                {
                   item.InvokeMember("click");
                   break;
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm getting on

```
HtmlElementCollection items = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
```

Null exception.

I tried to add before this line a loop:

```
while (webBrowser2.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                return;
            }
```

But then it didn't do anything when the page loaded.
It's never got to to the next lines.
I just saw the page loading in the webBrowser.

Comment: You are getting null reference exception because `this.webBrowser1.Document` is null. Because you navigated in `webBrowser2`. Also when using `DocumentCompleted` event you don't need such `while` loop.

Comment: A NRE is something that every developer hits at some point.  The best thing you can do to arm yourself against it is learn how to debug - [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) goes over it in a more general sense.

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting null reference exception because `this.webBrowser1.Document` is null.

`Document` property of `WebBrowser` is null before navigation.

You navigated in `webBrowser2` and your `webBrowser1.Document` is still null.